# Measure width of every line of multiline textview

Tags: android, textview, measure

I have a textview with multi-line text and I want to measure pixel width of each line. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] line = textView.getText().toString().split("\n");
ArrayList<Float> lineWidths = new ArrayList<Float>();
float textViewWidth = textView.getWidth() - textView.getPaddingLeft() - textView.getPaddingRight();
for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    float width = textView.getPaint().measureText(line[i]);
    if (width <= textViewWidth) {
        lineWidths.add(width);
    } else {
        int m = (int) (width / textViewWidth);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            lineWidths.add(textViewWidth);
        }
        lineWidths.add(width - textViewWidth * m);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if line is broke by too long string?